# Converting string array to Name/Value object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently am dealing with a Web Service that is returning an array of strings to the client.  From here I would like to take this array of strings and convert it into an object that gives each string a name so to reference it later.

So start with this:

```
var result = ["test", "hello", "goodbye"];
```

And I would like to end up with this:

```
var final = [{'value': "test"}, {'value': "hello"}, {'value': "goodbye"}];
```

I use jquery.  Is there a easy to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var final = $.map(result, function(val) {
    return { value: val };
});
```

Alternatively you can use the ES5 alternative

```
var final result.map(function(val) {
    return { value: val };
});
```

Or a simple iteration.

```
var final = [];
for (var i = 0, ii = result.length; i < ii; i++) {
    final.push({ value: result[i] });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think jQuery has to be used here.

```
var result = ["test", "hello", "goodbye"];
var final = [];
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    final.push({value: result[i]})
}
```

Comment: for(i in result) would give the same answer with less typing

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw: Be careful with that, prototype functions would suddenly be in the array too.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Figured there would be a caveat.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but you can do something like

`$(result).map(function(){return {'value':this}}`);

Comment: Try this: `var result = $(result).map(function() { return {'value': this}; });`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```
var input = ["one", "two", "three"], 
    output = [],
    obj;

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    obj = { "value" : input[i] };

    output.push(obj);

}
```

Link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/9Grvs/)